# PHP Syntax Error in the Instance Declaration

Tags: php, php-5.4

i have a little syntax error which i'm not able to sort out, can anyone help ?

Syntax:
[image]

Config Class:
[image]

Error:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Do not instantiate private variables like that, you should only be using them for declaring properties and simple values.

You cannot declare a private variable (declaring them a return value from a static functions at least) like that, just do it in the `constructor __construct()` for the object. You will get the same error for any class you do with a private variable declaration like that and setting it as a return value for any function. Try running the below in [PHPFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/) and you'll get the same error.

```
<?php
class A {
    private $hi = B::some_function('hi');
}

class B {
    public static function some_function(string) {
        return $string;
    }
}
?>
```

Instead do something like:

```
<?php
class A {
    private $hi;
    public function __construct()  {
        $this->hi = B::some_function('hi');
    }
}

class B {
    public static function some_function(string) {
        return $string;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: thanks alot, i've done in __construct() this with some other variables but never new it can generate an error thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is incorrect as I've seen in that picture, simply because **you didn't have a closing bracket '}' for the class User**.

Comment: well i have the closing brackets and everything,
if i do $_table = 'String' its working perfectly but not with Config::get Method

Comment: correct me if i'm wrong but is that really $_seassionTable? I think that's the problem with your code.

Comment: Please try to update your picture, because i think there are some things that you've already edited there like the one I've mentioned earlier, that I haven't seen any closing bracket in your class User.

Comment: no i haven't edited anything, and what you mean by $_seassionTable is a problem ?, and in users class there is much more code below, that's why you can not see the closing brackets. its a Portable library i'm working on, but this error stucks here.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this one. 
Use semicolon for every function call as shown below,

```
$_table = Config::get('tables/users');
$_seassionsTable = Config::get('tables/user_sessions');
```

It may be fix your issue.

Comment: no this won't work, syntax in not wrong the way you think. i'm declaring multiple variables so it needs ',' for separation not ';'